# Path does not exists in powershell foreach script

Tags: powershell

I'm having a strange situation, and I can't figure out the problem. I want the get the ACL and the AccessRules for all subdirectories of a given path. If I do them individually, I don't get any errors

```
gci -recurse | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } | Get-Acl | Format-List | Out-File C:\temp\permission.txt
gci -recurse | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } | Get-Acl | foreach {$_.GetAccessRules($true, $true, [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])} | Out-File C:\temp\permission1.txt -Append
```

However, I want to execute this in a foreach loop, to manipulate and handle better how the file is generated. Here's what I'm trying to do in my script:

```
sl c:\test_folder
gci * -Recurse | Export-Csv c:\temp\dir.csv -Force
$pastas = gci -Recurse | where {$_.PsIsContainer}
if (Test-Path C:\temp\permission.txt)
{
  ri c:\temp\permission.txt
}
foreach ($pasta in $pastas)
{
  $pasta
  Test-Path $pasta
  $acl = get-acl $pasta
  $acl | format-list | Out-File -FilePath c:\temp\permission1.txt -Append
  $acl.GetAccessRules($true, $true, [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]) | Out-File -FilePath c:\temp\permission1.txt -Append
}
```

While I'm processing in the `foreach` the folders directly in the root of the `$pastas` variable, the `Test-Path` returns `true`. In the first sub-directory however, the `Test-Path` returns `false`, but the folder does exist. On the get-acl, I get PathNotFound exception:

```
Get-Acl : Não é possível localizar o caminho 'Exportacao' porque ele não existe.
Em C:\Temp\Script Get Info.ps1:12 caractere:17
+   $acl = get-acl <<<<  $pasta
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Get-Acl], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetAcl_PathNotFound_Exception,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetAclCommand
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sl c:\test_folder
gci * -Recurse | Export-Csv c:\temp\dir.csv -Force
$pastas = gci -Recurse | where {$_.PsIsContainer}
if (Test-Path C:\temp\permission.txt)
{
  ri c:\temp\permission.txt
}
foreach ($pasta in $pastas)
{
  $pasta.FullName
  Test-Path $pasta.FullName
  $acl = get-acl $pasta.FullName
  $acl | format-list | Out-File -FilePath c:\temp\permission1.txt -Append
  $acl.GetAccessRules($true, $true, [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]) | Out-File -      FilePath c:\temp\permission1.txt -Append
}
```

Try the above script.

The reason that your code was failing is because $pasta is a FileInfo object and the Test-Path needs a string with the full path.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
Test-Path $pasta.fullname
  $acl = get-acl $pasta.fullname
```

Comment: tks for your answer, which is correct as well. Russllds was a little more complete, and has a lot less points then you, so I marked he's as the answer.

Comment: No problems. I'm here to help. You don't need to explain your choice :)