# How can I search through millions of files, and return a list of files owned by specific users?

Tags: file, powershell

Hello and Thanks for reading!

I'm working on coming up with a solution to the problem mentioned in the title, and my tool of choice is currently Powershell v5. Here's the source code I'm using, borrowed from here:

https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27829378/Find-files-owned-by-specific-users-in-a-shared-directory-sub-directories.html

Here's my work-in-progress code:

```
$Users = @('DOMAIN\user1','COMAIN\user2')
$NetworkSharePath = "\\filer\directory\subdirectory"

$Files = gci $NetworkSharePath -recurse | ? {$_.PsIsContainer -eq $False}
foreach ($File in $Files)
{
    Write-Host "Processing File: $($File.FullName)"
```

The line below is used to add in an "Owner" member to each file, which I evaluate to see if the file is owned by the users defined in the $Users array.

```
 $File | Add-Member -MemberType "NoteProperty" -Name "Owner" -Value (($File | Get-Acl).Owner.ToString())
}
```

Here's the part I'm struggling on - I want the Where-Object portion to return Owners that match one of the usernames in $Users array, and save it to a file that I can use for a file copy (backup) function that I haven't defined yet.

```
$Files | Select FullName, Owner | ? {$_.Owner -contains $Users}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to test element through the $User array, you should invert your statements :

```
{$Users -contains $_.Owner}
```

Then if your want to append that file name to a report file use the foreach-object operator

```
$Files | Select FullName, Owner | ? {$Users -contains $_.Owner} | % { Add-Content $destinationFilePath $_.FullName }
```

Answer (score 0):

@freakydinde has answered about the bug; I want to suggest that for millions of files, going through them once and gathering the names will take time, then you'll have a big list in memory and going over that list again to get the owner will take time. Then going over that list again to select the answers will take time. I think it would be neater running through the pipeline, chaining the steps in one go, and catching the pipeline output along the way.

- Get the files and their owners and save that information
- Then filter it later, so if something is going wrong while filtering it, you don't need to touch every file again.

e.g.

```
Get-ChildItem "\\filer\directory\subdirectory" -Recurse -File | ForEach-Object {

    Write-Host "Processing File: $_"

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        FullName = $_.FullName
        Owner = (Get-Acl -LiteralPath $_.FullName).Owner.ToString()
    }

} | Tee-Object -Variable files | Export-CSV all-files-and-owners.csv -NoTypeInformation

$Users = @('DOMAIN\user1','COMAIN\user2')
$Files | Where-Object {$_.Owner -in $Users}
```

And then you can come back to it much more easily with `$files = Import-CSV all-files-and-owners.csv` and try filtering for different users, without having to wait to access all the files again.

NB. You're using `$_.PSIsContainer` to exclude directories, which is a way of making it PowerShell v2 compatible. Newer `Get-ChildItem` supports `-Directory` and `-File` to only get one type of result. However you're also using `-contains` which is not PowerShell v2 compatible, which is why I changed it to use `gci -File`.

And `-in` which is a counterpart to `-contains` but tests membership the other way. `collection -contains item` or `item -in collection`

---

**Auto-generated PS help links from my codeblock** (if available):

- [`Get-ChildItem`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113308) (in module `Microsoft.PowerShell.Management`)
- [`ForEach-Object`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113300)
- [`Write-Host`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113426) (in module `Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility`)
- [`Get-Acl`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113305) (in module `Microsoft.PowerShell.Security`)
- [`Tee-Object`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113417) (in module `Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility`)
- [`Export-Csv`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113299) (in module `Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility`)
- [`Where-Object`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113423)

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown on the explanation - that really helps me absorb what you're saying (I'm new to coding). When I run the snippet you provided, I receive a message that indicates "Cannot find path '<name of file.extension>' because it does not exist. From what I've read here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121316/path-does-not-exists-in-powershell-foreach-script ), getting the ACL on the file is a two-step process and during the first pass, the filepath is changed in a way that makes the second pass fail at reading the filename, or somethign to that effect.

Comment: Tagging @TessellatingHeckler correctly this time. :)  Based on some web research I've been doing, it looks like it is possible to work-around the bug with get-acl, but in doing so, the examples I've seen all require a file list to already be available?

Comment: *Haven't figured out how to edit existing comments yet*  Here is the link that talks about the quotes being removed during the file scanning: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/cf87df79-76f7-48fe-8b5c-5fe49e829fc7/getacl-no-literal-path-support-arghh?forum=ITCG

Comment: @BrandonJ actually, if you're in PowerShell 4 or above you can use `(Get-Acl -LiteralPath $_.FullName)` which should fix it. Edited it into my answer.

Comment: I'm using Powershell v5 (verified that yesterday). I added in the -LiteralPath parameter, and it looks like the script is waiting for me to type the path out (which is what I was afraid of happening). Is there a way to paste in codeblocks in replies? Also, does your original answer have all of the code in it, or am I supposed to add in some of the original pieces from my original submission?

Comment: @BrandonJ Waiting for you to type the path out? Like what? I can't make Get-Acl prompt me for a path at all. My answer was intended to be complete - and it appears to work when I run it, it fills a CSV of filenames and owners - although you can edit it however you want. It is possible to put code in comments by surrounding it with backticks, but the StackOverflow intent is for you to edit your original question and update it with the current state and progress on the problem so other people can answer - or if it's a big change from the original, to post a new question for the new problem.

Comment: Another note: Depending on the amount of files and the memory available, using the Pipe might not always be the best option. While it is most certainly the safest option (since it will never use much ram), `(Get-ChildItem "\\filer\directory\subdirectory" -Recurse -File).ForEach{<restofthecode>}` is quite a bit quicker if you have enough memory.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler I updated the original question, per your suggestion.